# Record rtmp stream to multi flv files

Tags: h.264, rtmp, flv

I'm currently write rtmp server to receive rtmp stream, then record to multi flv file, segment base on time.

Example: 1 minute -> 1 flv file, 2m -> 2 flv file...

Problem: only the first flv file is playable, from the second onwards, they are not playable, maybe they miss some metadata of the codec (h264).

How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: Can't your code just make a **new** _"first flv file"_ every time you need to segment? The code could also set name for saving, so just `+1` some counting variable and set that number as save/file name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a header, as well as sequence headers depending on the codec used. The segments must also be split on keyframes. The FLV formate is well documented here https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'm missing video stream metadata. Because metadata video exists only 1st flv file.

Comment: The AMF tag is not need/used.